# std::bind and variadic template function

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, variadic-templates, stdbind

Is this even possible?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

enum class Enum {a, b, c };

class Dispatch {
    public:
    void check(uint16_t) { std::cout << "check 16\n"; }
    void check(uint32_t) { std::cout << "check 32\n"; }
    void check(uint64_t) { std::cout << "check 64\n"; }

    template<Enum E, typename... A>
    void event(A&&... args) {
        tag_event(Tag<E>(), std::forward<A>(args)...);
    }

    private:
    template<Enum E> struct Tag {};    
    void tag_event(Tag<Enum::a>, uint16_t) { std::cout << "a\n"; }
    void tag_event(Tag<Enum::b>, uint16_t) { std::cout << "b\n"; }
    void tag_event(Tag<Enum::c>, uint16_t) { std::cout << "c\n"; }
};

void exec(std::function<void()>&& func) { func(); }

int main() {
    Dispatch d;

    // all good    
    exec(std::bind(static_cast<void(Dispatch::*)(uint16_t)>(&Dispatch::check), &d, uint16_t()));
    exec(std::bind(static_cast<void(Dispatch::*)(uint32_t)>(&Dispatch::check), &d, uint32_t()));
    exec(std::bind(static_cast<void(Dispatch::*)(uint64_t)>(&Dispatch::check), &d, uint64_t()));

    // all good
    d.event<Enum::a>(uint16_t());
    d.event<Enum::b>(uint16_t());
    d.event<Enum::c>(uint16_t());

    // but how do we bind an event<> call?
    exec(std::bind(static_cast<void(Dispatch::*)(uint16_t)>(&Dispatch::event<Enum::a>), &d, uint16_t()));
}
```

So I'm trying to bind a call to the variadic template method but get the following compiler error...

```
In function 'int main()':
42:86: error: no matches converting function 'event' to type 'void (class Dispatch::*)(uint16_t) {aka void (class Dispatch::*)(short unsigned int)}'
13:10: note: candidate is: template<Enum E, class ... A> void Dispatch::event(A&& ...)
```

Any suggestions short of exposing all the tag overloads instead?

Comment: Why not use a lambda? Way more straightforward.

Comment: Lambdas are your friend: `exec([&](){ d.event<Enum::a>(uint16_t{}); });`

Comment: I still sometimes wonder why it was not deprecated as the rest of the `*_function` were.

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher One "reason": http://www.sdowney.org/2017/06/why-stdbind-cant-be-formally-deprecated/

Comment: @NathanOliver Thanks for the link!

Comment: @NathanOliver That did the trick.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to pass through a lambda function, as suggested in comments.

Anyway, if you want to pass to `std::bind()`, seems to me that a possible solution is

```
// ..................................................VVVVVVVV  <-- ad this
exec(std::bind(static_cast<void(Dispatch::*)(uint16_t const &)>
     (&Dispatch::event<Enum::a, uint16_t const &>), &d, uint16_t()));
// ...........................^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^  <-- and this
```

I mean: you have to select the `event()` method explicating also the received type; I suggest `uint16_t const &` (instead of `uint16_t`) that is compatible with universal reference signature of your `event()` method (I suppose other combinations are possible but for a `uint16_t` activate move semantics... I suppose it's superfluous).